# WHERE EXISTS not working

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I know I can do this with a table join, however, I'm trying to do it with a WHERE EXISTS clause. I know there are 65 matches, nonetheless, the sub query is not working. It brings all the values from table scrubs.

pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID` has many duplicates values that why I use DISTINCT in the sub query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.`BW Parent Number`
FROM scrubs sc
WHERE EXISTS (

    SELECT DISTINCT pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID`
    FROM pdwspend
    WHERE pdwspend.`BU ID` = 'BU_1'
    AND pdwspend.version LIKE '%GOV%'
    )
AND SC.`year` =2014
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want a correlated subquery.  Right now, the `exists` either finds a row (and everything is returned) or finds no row (and nothing is returned).  Here is a guess as what the query you want looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.`BW Parent Number`
FROM scrubs sc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM pdwspend s
              WHERE s.`BU ID` = 'BU_1' AND s.version LIKE '%GOV%' AND
                    s.`Child Supplier ID` = sc.`BW Parent Number` 
             ) AND
      SC.`year` = 2014;
```

Also note that `distinct` is not needed for `exists` subqueries.

Comment: `BW Parent Number` = `Child Supplier ID` , however, `Child Supplier ID` has many duplicates

Comment: @nangys . . . The duplicates do not matter in an `exists` clause.

Comment: thanks for the help. I used your query, however, for some reason mysql keeps crashing. any idea?

Comment: "crashing" . . . that is rather extreme.  This query could create problems of various sorts -- performance or syntax errors, for example.  I don't see how this would "crash" your server.